# load a file and read the information in the file

Tags: upload

I am looking to open an excel file via an apex dialog box, then browse the information in my file line by line and display them with visualforce

Comment: Hello, This is just the requirement, what have you tried so far? Are you stuck anywhere?

Comment: Yes, and when I choose my excel file here is the error that it shows me:13:52:13:012 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [15]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string"|0x4e4728

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please make sure to include the relevant portions of your code, along with the specific issue you are struggling with and the complete text and location of any errors. See [ask] for more about our expectations, and please [edit] your question to add information rather than posting comments.

Comment: You can't directly read an Excel file. Try using a CSV instead.

Comment: Yes that's what I did but it shows me an error:
13:52:13:012 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [15]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string"|0x4e4728